# Grayscaling in IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, grayscale

I have a problem with my gallery and I don`t know how to fix that.
I use grayscale effect for my photos based on this site recommendations (http://webdesignerwall.com/demo/html5-grayscale/) Everything works well in FF and Chrome, but in IE all images are not displayed correctly (overlapped).

My code is:

```
    function grayscale(src){
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var imgObj = new Image();
        imgObj.src = src;
        canvas.width = imgObj.width;
        canvas.height = imgObj.height; 
        ctx.drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0); 
        var imgPixels = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for(var y = 0; y < imgPixels.height; y++){
            for(var x = 0; x < imgPixels.width; x++){
                var i = (y * 4) * imgPixels.width + x * 4;
                var avg = (imgPixels.data[i] + imgPixels.data[i + 1] + imgPixels.data[i + 2]) / 3;
                imgPixels.data[i] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 1] = avg; 
                imgPixels.data[i + 2] = avg;
            }
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imgPixels, 0, 0, 0, 0, imgPixels.width, imgPixels.height);
        return canvas.toDataURL();
    }
                // Fade in images so there isn't a color "pop" document load and then on window load

    $(".item img").animate({opacity:1},0);

    // clone image
    $('a.thumb img').each(function(){
        var el = $(this);
        el.css({"position":"absolute"}).wrap("<div class='img_wrapper' style='display: inline-block'>").clone().addClass('img_grayscale').css({"position":"absolute","z-index":"998","opacity":"0"}).insertBefore(el).queue(function(){
            var el = $(this);
            el.parent().css({"width":this.width,"height":this.height});
            el.dequeue();
        });
        this.src = grayscale(this.src);
    });

    // Fade image 
    $('a.thumb img').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('img:first').stop().animate({opacity:1}, 0);
    })
    $('.img_grayscale').mouseout(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:0}, 0);
    });
```

I also attached an image with displayed photos in IE9 (http://postimage.org/image/8w0hnqnbl/
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this also happen when you are not using the script? Can you post a test case/fiddle?

Comment: Me thinks your problem is with `display: inline-block`, check to see it IE9 is rendering in compatibility or quirks mode ? Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but try `float:left` or to make the position relative, and see it that helps.

Comment: No chance nor with float:left or position relative.